# Implement Infinite Vector Space in Haskell as mapping from Integers to Scalars

Tags: haskell, math, vector, types

I'm trying to implement an infinite dimensional vector space in Haskell, but I'm running into trouble. I would use a stream as the base data type and simply use the provided package for vector spaces, but I want indices to go in both the negative and positive direction. In other words, I want some sort of mapping from the integers (all of them) to some scalar values. This can be easily implemented as, say,

```hs
(^+^) :: (Integer -> Double) -> (Integer -> Double) -> (Integer -> Double)
a ^+^ b = (\ n -> (a n) + (b n))
(^*^) :: Double -> (Integer -> Double) -> (Integer -> Double)
c ^*^ a = (\ n -> c * (a n))
```

And used like

```hs
vecA :: (Integer -> Double)
vecB :: (Integer -> Double)
vecA n = fromInteger n
vecB n = fromInteger n
print ((vecA ^+^ vecB) 4) --prints 8.0, as expected
```

Okay, so I would like to make this far more general, and naïvely, I would want to write something like,

```hs
class AdditiveGroup v where
  -- | The zero element: identity for '(^+^)'
  zeroV :: v
  -- | Add vectors
  (^+^) :: v -> v -> v
  -- | Additive inverse
  negateV :: v -> v
  -- | Group subtraction
  (^-^) :: v -> v -> v
  v ^-^ v' = v ^+^ negateV v'

class AdditiveGroup v => VectorSpace v where
  type Scalar v :: *
  -- | Scale a vector
  (*^) :: Scalar v -> v -> v
```

(I copied and pasted this definition from Haskell's classes for this kind of thing.) But, of course, there's not a way (that I can see) to implement the mapping I had above as a data construct, and trying to change the kind of v makes me run into problems

```hs
--This doesn't even compile
class InfVecSpace v where
    type Index v  :: *
    type Scalar v :: *
    type Member v :: * -> *
    (^+^)   :: (Member v) -> (Member v) -> (Member v)
    zeroV   :: (Member v)
    invertV :: (Member v) -> (Member v)
    (^*^)   :: Scalar v -> (Member v) -> (Member v)
```

How might I implement this, preferably as idiomatically as possible, within Haskell's type system?

Comment: You need to add another parameter wherever you use `(Member v)` because it's of kind `*->*` but it needs to be `*`.

Comment: What would this parameter look like, in this case? I want these functions to output functions. (I.e., things of kind * -> *)

Comment: Functions have arrow types; function types have kind `*`; type functions have kinds with arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to create a new class; instead, simply make an instance of the old classes for the function type. Thus, for example:

```
instance AdditiveGroup v => AdditiveGroup (e -> v) where
    zeroV _ = zeroV
    (f ^+^ g) x = f x ^+^ g x
    negateV f x = negateV (f x)

instance VectorSpace v => VectorSpace (e -> v) where
    type Scalar (e -> v) = Scalar v
    (a *^ f) x = a *^ f x
```

Comment: Instances like that tend to lead to bad type errors, which is why `Reader` is useful.